# Exporting data from mysql table to a .csv file

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv

I have a mysql table in which I store cellphone numbers of the users, and now I want to export only those numbers to a .csv file using php, and I don't want to use a comma in the end of each number. Now suppose I have the next 3 numbers stored in my table:

```
123456789
+966123456789  
00966123456789
```

Now if I used the next code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT cellphone FROM user");
if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $cellphones .= $row["cellphone"] . ",\r\n"; //note the comma here
    }
}

$filename = "cellphones_" . date("Y-m-d_H-i");
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header("Content-disposition: filename=" . $filename . ".csv");
print $cellphones;
exit;
```

I will get a .csv file in which I have the numbers like this:

```
+966123456789,
00966123456789,
123456789,
```

But if I used the same code without the comma like this:

```
    $cellphones .= $row["cellphone"] . "\r\n";
```

instead of:

```
    $cellphones .= $row["cellphone"] . ",\r\n"; //note the comma here
```

then numbers in the .csv file will be:

```
9.66123E+11
9.66123E+11
123456789
```

So what is the wrong and how can I get the numbers appear correctly without the comma?

Comment: That's an issue with Excel, rather than your CSV, I suspect. Try looking at the file in Notepad to see what you're generating.

Comment: $cellphones .= '"' . $row["cellphone"] . '"' . "\r\n";

Comment: @andrewsi I've already tried to export these numbers to a .txt file without a comma and it works perfectly. The problem appears when I try to export them to a .csv file as I explained.

Comment: @Amr - what's the difference between a .txt file and .csv file?

Comment: @andrewsi It's the client that wants the numbers in a .csv file

Comment: @MarkBaker I've tried your line of code, but it gives the same result.

Comment: @Amr - are you positive? Are you testing in MS EXcel (if so, which version) or other spreadsheet program? In that case, you might be scuppered with CSV

Comment: Works for Open/Libre office, but not for MS EXcel or Gnumeric - I think the problem may be the fact that you're using CSV for a single value rather than multiple cells

Comment: @MarkBaker Very good explanation, may be the problem is in the MS Excel as you say

Comment: That's why I prefer real Excel files for reading in Excel; but if this is for somebody to load into their apps vis scripts or whatever, rather than just viewing in MS Excel, then quote marks should work

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation**

The comma is being treated as part of the value in each line, so MS Excel treats the data as a string when it imports.... meaning that it will be stored in the cell "as is". Without the comma, MS Excel treates the value as a number, using general formatting which doesn't display leading zeroes, and which switches to scientific format if the number exceeds a defined number of digits.

**Solution**

In order to always treat the value as a string, without the comma, enclose the value in double quote marks.

```
$cellphones .= '"' . $row["cellphone"] . '"' . "\r\n";
```